# Change ball angle when hit another body (Paddle)

Tags: flutter, dart, game-development, box2d, flame

I'm studying Flame + Forge2D, developing the famous breakout game. I'm struggling with changing the ball's direction when it hits the paddle.
Imagine a paddle with size 6, when the ball hits paddle's "position":

- (0,1) -> Go Left
- (2,3) -> Go straight up
- (4,5) -> Go Right

It should "ignore" from which position the ball is coming from, and change the ball's angle according to the steps above, while **keeping the velocity the same**!

My code so far:

```
@override
  void beginContact(Object other, Contact contact) {
    super.beginContact(other, contact);

    if (other is Paddle) {
      final ballManifold = WorldManifold();
      contact.getWorldManifold(ballManifold);

      final intersection = ballManifold.points[0] / 20;
      var localIntersection = body.localPoint(intersection);

      final double fraction = localIntersection.x / other.size.width / 2;

      final Vector2 direction = body.linearVelocity;
      if (fraction < 0.33) {
        body.linearVelocity += Vector2(-direction.x, direction.y);
        print('left');
      } else if (fraction < 0.67) {
        body.linearVelocity = Vector2(0.0, -10.0);
        print('cenbter');
      } else {
        body.linearVelocity += Vector2(direction.x, direction.y);
        print('right');
      }
    } else if (other is PowerUp) {
      // body.applyLinearImpulse(Vector2(15, 15));
      other.hasCollidedWithBall(body);
      gameRef.paddle.increaseSize();
    }
  }
```

Ball:

```
@override
  Body createBody() {
    final bodyDef = BodyDef()
      ..type = BodyType.dynamic
      ..userData = this
      ..position = position;

    final ball = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    final fixtureDef = FixtureDef(CircleShape()..radius = radius)
      ..restitution = 1
      ..friction = 0
      ..density = 1;
    ball.createFixture(fixtureDef);

    return ball;
  }
```

Paddle:

```
@override
  Body createBody() {
    final bodyDef = BodyDef()
      ..type = BodyType.dynamic
      ..position = position
      ..fixedRotation = true
      ..angularDamping = 1
      ..linearDamping = 10;

    final paddleBody = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    final shape = PolygonShape()
      ..setAsBox(size.width / 2, size.height / 2, Vector2.zero(), 0);

    paddleBody.createFixture(
      FixtureDef(shape)
        ..density = 100
        ..userData = this
        ..friction = 0
        ..restitution = 1,
    );

    return paddleBody;
  }
```

Very important info:

- Ball and Paddle are BodyComponent;
- This snippet is inside Ball's component;
- My game has gravity = Vector2.zero() and zoom = 20;
- The paddle may increase or decrease width during the game;

It's super ok to answer in another language (not dart), Forge2D is a Box2D implementation in dart, I'm just trying to figure out the algorithm here!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To change the velocity in Forge2D you shouldn't directly edit it, you have to change it by applying forces or impulses to the ball.

The easiest is to use `body.applyLinearImpulse(Vector2)`.
You can also use `body.applyForce(Vector2)`, but that usually requires you to do more manual  calculations.

Comment: Thanks! I may not have been clear. What I mean is, I'm trying to understand how can I know which part of the paddle the ball has hit. It is giving me strange portions (as in the print)

Comment: Ah, I see! Why are you dividing the first intersection point with 20, which I assumes is the zoom level?

Comment: Exactly, and gravity = Vector2.zero()

Comment: But why are you dividing by it? You're doing all calculations in the world coordinate system anyways?

Comment: Hmm good point, perhaps I didn't understand the docs. So I shouldn't divide by 20? And the rest of the logic, is it correct?